# Restrict IAM ec2:CopySnapshot action on snapshots with specific key value

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, snapshot

I have few ec2 snapshots with tags as key **ce** and value **ae-12** . I want to allow the role to perform action of ec2:CopySnapshot on the snapshots containing the above mentioned tags only.
I'm using the below policy but it doesn't work:

```
{
            "Sid": "snapshare",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:CopySnapshot"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "ec2:ResourceTag/ce": "ae-12"
                }
            }
        }
```

I also tried "aws:ResourceTag/ce": "yes" in the condition block but it fail too.

Can anyone help me how to tackle this via IAM policy?

Comment: Do you have any other IAM Policy attached to that role?

Answer (score 0):

Several things to consider:

1. Check supported condition keys for ec2:CopySnapshot

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazonec2.html

2. If you want to block

   ```
   ec2:CopySnapshot
   ```

   use

   ```
   "Effect": "Deny"
   ```

   and negative condition

   ```
   "ForAnyValue:StringNotEquals": { "aws:TagKeys": ["ce"] }
   ```
3. Unfortunately you can limit Condition to Tag Key only for this action.

Comment: I tried this but it denies for everything, I tried to generate a unique key say ce-123 and then attached the below permission

{
            "Sid": "CopySnap",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": "ec2:CopySnapshot",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:*::snapshot/*",
            "Condition": {
                "ForAnyValue:StringNotEquals": {
                    "aws:TagKeys": [
                        "ce-123"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }

Comment: You also need to add Allow on "ec2:CopySnapshot". Action is allowed when it's not explicitly denied and it's explicitly allowed.

Comment: You mean there should be one more statement with allow for copysnapshot action?

Comment: Check this doc:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_evaluation-logic.html

The idea is to allow action and not deny it. So whenever the condition in deny part of your policy is met, action is not denied, however, you still need part of the policy to allow this action.

Check this policy https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_iam_multiple-services-console.html
It allows s3:* on every bucket, however denies s3:* on logs bucket.

Answer (score -1):

The ec2:CopySnapshot action does not directly operate on the snapshot itself but on the source snapshot specified during the copy. Therefore, the condition in your policy should be applied to the source snapshot rather than the destination snapshot.

Following is the corrected policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ec2:CopySnapshot",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "ec2:ResourceTag/ce": "ae-12"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This policy allows the role to perform ec2:CopySnapshot on any resource ("*") but only if the source snapshot has the specified tag ("ce:ae-12").

Make sure that the snapshots you are copying have the correct tag ("ce:ae-12") on the source side. The policy is checking the tag of the source snapshot during the copy operation.

Also, ensure that the IAM role associated with the user has this policy attached and that there are no conflicting policies that might restrict the action. If the issue persists, check CloudTrail logs for any error messages that might provide additional insights into the problem.